Which Monty Python's Flying Circus episode is this sketch about extremism from?
Which Monty Python's episode is this sketch about extremism from?




How do you know it is from Flying Circus? The lack of audience laughter leads me to think it is not.

As a reminder, John Cleese has an EXTENSIVE filmography. Monty Python/Flying Circus is just a tiny tiny bit of it http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000092/

This is not from Monty Python's Flying Circus. John Cleese filmed it for a 1987 election campaign. From Wikipedia:

Cleese switched to the [Social Democratic Party] after their formation in 1981, and during the 1987 general election, Cleese recorded a nine-minute party political broadcast for the SDP-Liberal Alliance, which spoke about the similarities and failures of the other two parties in a more humorous tone than standard political broadcasts.

Here's a longer clip:




I must learn to type faster...

Sorry :) Figured I won't be the only one posting this

Why do I even bother to pull up Google when an ID question comes up, dang you Walt.

And more to the point, Cleese even makes fun of people thinking the clip is part of the Python Repeats. HA!
